# How to detect dialog's close event?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Hi everyone.

I am making a GUI application using python3.4, PyQt5 in windows 7.

Application is very sample. User clicks a main window's button, information dialog pops up. And when a user clicks information dialog's close button (window's X button), system shows confirm message. This is all.

Here's my code.

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialog, QLabel

class mainClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        openDlgBtn = QPushButton("openDlg", self)
        openDlgBtn.clicked.connect(self.openChildDialog)
        openDlgBtn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.show()

    def openChildDialog(self):
        childDlg = QDialog(self)
        childDlgLabel = QLabel("Child dialog", childDlg)

        childDlg.resize(100, 100)
        childDlg.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mc = mainClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Result screen shot is...

[image]

[image]

In this situation, I've added these code in mainClass class.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    print("X is clicked")
```

This code works only when the main window is closed. But what I want is closeEvent function works when childDlg is to closed. Not main window.

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have added, the method `closeEvent` in the class `mainClass`.
So you have reimplemented the method `closeEvent` of your `QMainwindow` and not the method `closeEvent` of your `childDlg`. To do it, you have to subclass your `chilDlg` like this:

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialog, QLabel

class ChildDlg(QDialog):
   def closeEvent(self, event):
      print("X is clicked")

class mainClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        openDlgBtn = QPushButton("openDlg", self)
        openDlgBtn.clicked.connect(self.openChildDialog)
        openDlgBtn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.show()

    def openChildDialog(self):
        childDlg = ChildDlg(self)
        childDlgLabel = QLabel("Child dialog", childDlg)

        childDlg.resize(100, 100)
        childDlg.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mc = mainClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialog, QLabel

class mainClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        openDlgBtn = QPushButton("openDlg", self)
        openDlgBtn.clicked.connect(self.openChildDialog)
        openDlgBtn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.show()

    def openChildDialog(self):
        childDlg = QDialog(self)
        childDlgLabel = QLabel("Child dialog", childDlg)

        childDlg.closeEvent = self.CloseEvent

        childDlg.resize(100, 100)
        childDlg.show()

    def CloseEvent(self, event):
        print("X is clicked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mc = mainClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```